# What is the time complexity of next() function in python?

Tags: python

What is the time complexity of `next()` function in python? I can't seem to find the documentation for it.

Example usage (from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_next.htm):

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
print "Name of the file: ", fo.name

# Assuming file has following 5 lines
# This is 1st line
# This is 2nd line
# This is 3rd line
# This is 4th line
# This is 5th line

for index in range(5):
   line = fo.next()
   print "Line No %d - %s" % (index, line)

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Comment: It does a single operation and no iterations, hence O(1).

Comment: You mean specifically when iterating over a file object, or in general? (In general, it can have any time complexity. It calls an arbitrary function.)

Comment: @Ry- when reading an input file

Comment: @FatihAkici: When talking about reading a file, that isn’t true.

Comment: @llamaro25: It depends on the file and filesystem in that case. Reading a file can also involve arbitrary functions going on elsewhere. A reasonable assumption is that the time it takes is proportional to the number of bytes in the line, though. (It can’t be *less* than that, at least.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not really relevant. We don't normally talk about time complexity of file I/O. Time complexity is about CPU time and file operations are dominated by I/O time (disk throughput and latency).

I suppose you could say it's O(*len*) where *len* is the length of the next line of input. But I would never really think that way. Big-O notation isn't generally something one considers when one's reading files.

Files are read in large multi-kilobyte chunks with lots of buffering at the OS and disk layer. OSes have page caches where blocks are cached in memory to avoid unnecessary disk access. Disks have read and write caches to minimize physical access and improve latency. If the file content is already in cache you get a 100X or 1000X speedup compared to when it needs to be read from physical media the first time. The file could be in a RAM tmpfs, on an SSD, or on a spinning platter HDD. Very different performance characteristics. It could be on a network file system, which is even slower yet.

Time complexity just isn't the right tool for the job.